# Is it possible to add the CXF interceptor for the interceptor chain of the all clients in the server with the one command?

Tags: cxf, cxf-client

I'am adding the CXF interceptor for the interceptor chain of the every client like this

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();
endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor(Phase.SEND));
```

Here the `port` is the port of the service the client uses.

Is it possible to add the `MyInterceptor` interceptor for the interceptor chain of the all clients in the server with the one command?

Comment: You mean you want to use a server-side interceptor instead of a client-side interceptor?

Comment: No. I want that all clients use the same interceptor. I don't have any access to the server code.